# Python application MQTT using paho & GUI using Tkinter significant performance issues (select.select)

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, mqtt, paho

I'm building an application which uses MQTT to publish/receive data with a simple GUI to display data received and on/off toggles which if changed a message is published using MQTT.

The application is functioning as intended but it's so laggy.

I used the CProfile and found out that the function that has the most allocated time to it is "select.select", so my question is how to improve my code's performance.
[CProfile Output(sort=tottime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqEqs.png) [CProfile Output(sort=cumtime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRHd2.png)

Note: I tried to run MQTT on a different thread but thing is I have to access Tkinter objects in MQTT functions which Tkinter doesn't allow (that's what I understood)

Rest of the code(if needed): https://www.codepile.net/pile/K2VvKz2y

```py
from tkinter import *
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import gui

running = True

def update_running():
    global running
    running = False
    root.destroy()


def update_meters(topic, value):
    if topic == "home/office/temperature":
        office_temperature_meter.reading.set(value)
    elif topic == "home/bed/temperature":
        bed_temperature_meter.reading.set(value)
    elif topic == "home/living/temperature":
        living_temperature_meter.reading.set(value)


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected With Result Code "+rc)


def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print(message.topic + " Received: " + message.payload.decode())
    update_meters(message.topic, message.payload.decode())


# Establishing Connection
broker_url = "iot.eclipse.org"
broker_port = 1883

client = mqtt.Client("G2K_RaspberryPie3_x01")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker_url, broker_port)

client.subscribe("home/office/temperature", qos=1)
client.subscribe("home/bed/temperature", qos=1)
client.subscribe("home/living/temperature", qos=1)
###########

# Initiating Main Application Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()
root.title("G2K: Smart Home")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", update_running)
###########

# Office Frame
office_frame = gui.FrameCreate(250, 650, "LightGrey", 20, 20, "Office", 85)
root.update()
office_lights_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 100, "Lights", office_frame.frame)
office_conditioner_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 200, "Air Conditioner", office_frame.frame)
office_temperature_meter = gui.ReadingMeter(10, 300, "Temperature", office_frame.frame)
###########

# Bedroom Frame
bed_frame = gui.FrameCreate(250, 650, "LightGrey", 300, 20, "Bedroom", 75)
root.update()
bed_lights_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 100, "Lights", bed_frame.frame)
bed_conditioner_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 200, "Air Conditioner", bed_frame.frame)
bed_temperature_meter = gui.ReadingMeter(10, 300, "Temperature", bed_frame.frame)
###########

# Livingroom Frame
living_frame = gui.FrameCreate(250, 650, "LightGrey", 590, 20, "Living Room", 60)
root.update()
living_lights_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 100, "Lights", living_frame.frame)
living_conditioner_button = gui.ToggleButton(10, 200, "Air Conditioner", living_frame.frame)
living_temperature_meter = gui.ReadingMeter(10, 300, "Temperature", living_frame.frame)
###########


while 1:
    if running:
        # constantly update the GUI
        root.update()
        # constantly check if any messages arrived on subscribed topics
        client.loop()

        # Check if state is not changed, to avoid sending redundant requests.
        if office_lights_button.button_state != office_lights_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/office/light", payload=int(office_lights_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            office_lights_button.button_prev_state = office_lights_button.button_state

        if office_conditioner_button.button_state != office_conditioner_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/office/conditioner", payload=int(office_conditioner_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            office_conditioner_button.button_prev_state = office_conditioner_button.button_state

        # Check if state is not changed, to avoid sending redundant requests.
        if bed_lights_button.button_state != bed_lights_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/bed/light", payload=int(bed_lights_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            bed_lights_button.button_prev_state = bed_lights_button.button_state

        if bed_conditioner_button.button_state != bed_conditioner_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/bed/conditioner", payload=int(bed_conditioner_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            bed_conditioner_button.button_prev_state = bed_conditioner_button.button_state

        # Check if state is not changed, to avoid sending redundant requests.
        if living_lights_button.button_state != living_lights_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/living/light", payload=int(living_lights_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            living_lights_button.button_prev_state = living_lights_button.button_state

        if living_conditioner_button.button_state != living_conditioner_button.button_prev_state:
            client.publish(topic="home/living/conditioner", payload=int(bed_conditioner_button.button_state), qos=1,
                           retain=False)
            living_conditioner_button.button_prev_state = living_conditioner_button.button_state
```

Comment: Have you gotten a fix?

Comment: @user1622343 nope

Answer (score 0):

Try out Client class `loop_start()` method. Since it runs of a seperate thread it dosnt effekt the GUIs mainloop too much. Ive only tried it in pyqt5 but it should work with tk as well.

Remove the while true loop and add `client.loop_start()` and tks mainloop at the end.

https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#client